# What is the proper definition of the CSS term '.override' ?

Tags: css, css-selectors, overriding

I occasionally see the term '.override' in css code samples (note the dot!)

I'm looking for a link to a formal authoritative definition, and can't find one.

It appears this allows one to override any property. But when I search for a definitive explanation of this feature, I find very little, including no mention of it at w3schools.

Am I misunderstanding this to be a css feature, versus some kind of convention I am seeing in demo code?

The word override is used descriptively so much, and I think search engines ignore the dot prefix, so finding info about '.override' has been tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an ordinary class selector matching elements like `<i class="override">`.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I'm confused by the fact that many samples do not include the companion html, which would make this clear.